# Black background top of the app screen phonegap ios

Tags: ios, cordova, statusbar

I am getting black background above the application top and not showing status bar. When i open childbrowser and close it the status bar will be shown. I am not getting what the issue is. please help me

Comment: Check that you have provided all images for splash screen.

Comment: y i provided all splash screen images, at the start when splash screen loads it shows the status bar, after home page load it disappears , and status bar shows when i open childbrowser , also after the close of childbrowser it shows the status bar.